# Calculate the magnitude and phase of a signal at a particular frequency in python

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, fft

I have a signal for which I need to calculate the magnitude and phase at 200 Hz frequency only. I would like to use Fourier transform for it. I am very new to signal processing. And this is my first time using a fourier transform.

I found that I can use the scipy.fftpack.fft to calculate the fft of the signal. Then use numpy.mag and numpyh.phase to calculate the magnitude and phases of the entire signal. But I would like to get the magnitude and phase value of the signal corresponding to 200 Hz frequency only. How can I do this using Python?

So far I have done.

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft
import numpy as np

fft_data = fft(signal)
magnitude = np.mag(fft_data)
phase = np.phase(fft_data)
```

Comment: You could apply a narrow band-pass filter centered on 200 Hz and calculate the magnitude and phase of the filtered result.

Comment: Keep in mind that the fft calculates the energy within a frequency band, not at a single frequency. It could be helpful to demodulate the signal at the desired frequency to get an accurate value of magnitude and phase

Comment: @Guimoute It needs to be a very special filter to keep the phase at the center frequency the same and be reasonably *useful* (steep edges and low to zero unit delay). In fact, the best filter I can think of is FFT-based and that's just a step beyond simply using FFT and extracting the necessary data directly.